# Absolute module imports @app with jest and CRA

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have my create-react-app bootstrap workspace setup to support module imports using @app/ as my root module.

I achieve this by adding this to my webpack config

```
     alias: {
    // Support React Native Web
    // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
    'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    '@app': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
  },
```

However this does not seem to work with my jest tests. Anytime something is imported with @app the import is not resolved.

Anyone have a good solution to this